# Passing variable into arrow function in eventListener

Tags: javascript, electron

a while back I needed to pass a variable to a function called from `addEventListener`.

```
for(let i of ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","-","*","/",".","(",")"]){
    document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click",()=>{add_chr(i)})
}
```

While this worked perfectly, I now need to have the function in the `{}` instead of `add_chr(i)`.
I have tried the following:

```
for (let i = 0; i < dict["files"].length; i++) {
  //i is undefined
  document.getElementById("rm" + i).addEventListener("click", (e, i) => {
    console.log(i)
    dict["files"].splice(i, 1)
    table()
  })
  //function does not execute
  document.getElementById("rm" + i).addEventListener("click", () => {
    (i) => {
      console.log(i)
      dict["files"].splice(i, 1)
      table()
    }
  })
}
```

This doesn't work, in the first event listener the `i` is undefined and the second function never executes. (I'm always using only one `addEventListener`, this is just to show my approach).
How can I pass the variable `i` to the function with/ without the `event` object?

Comment: This is just a friendly reminder that arrow functions do not work in old browsers like Internet Explorer. Arrow functions are not without their uses, but in this situation you could substitute a regular anonymous function and it would work just the same without breaking IE.

Comment: @PHPGuru Thanks for the information, but this is for an electron project which hopefully will never see IE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `i` from the anonymous function as it is hiding the `i` of the loop and fix the brackets of the second function.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // i is undefined
  document.getElementById("rm" + i).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(i);
  });
  // function does not execute
  document.getElementById("rm" + i).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="rm0">rm0</button>
<button id="rm1">rm1</button>
<button id="rm2">rm2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, try changing `let i = 0` to `var i = 0` and also remove `i` from your anonymous event handler, like this:

```
document.getElementById("rm" + i).addEventListener("click", (e) => { // etc.
```

Comment: i is always the last number of the for loop